# Calculating the time difference between two time stamp object - java

Tags: java, date, time, timestamp

I am having java.sql.date and java.sql.time objects, I need to find the time duration between the dates.

So i am creating java.sql.timestamp object by using above date and time object

```
  Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp(StartDate.getYear(),
        StartDate.getMonth(), StartDate.getDay(),
        StartTime.getHours(), StartTime.getMinutes(), 00,
        00);
```

Here is mycode

```
String date = "2010-01-05";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date date3 = null;
    try {
        date3 = sdf1.parse(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date StartDate = new Date(date3.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date " + StartDate);

    String date2 = "2010-01-06";
    java.util.Date date4 = null;
    try {
        date4 = sdf1.parse(date2);
    } catch (ParseException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    Date EndDate = new Date(date4.getTime());
    System.out.println("Date " + EndDate);

    String time = "01:00";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    java.sql.Time StartTime = null;
    try {
        StartTime = new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(time).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException exception2) {
        exception2.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("TIMEEEEEEEEEE====" + StartTime);

    String time2 = "02:00";
    java.sql.Time EndTime = null;
    try {
        EndTime = new java.sql.Time(formatter.parse(time2).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException exception3) {
        exception3.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("TIMEEEEEEEEEE====" + EndTime);


    Timestamp timestamp1 = new Timestamp(StartDate.getYear(),
            StartDate.getMonth(), StartDate.getDay(),
            StartTime.getHours(), StartTime.getMinutes(), 00,
            00);
    Timestamp timestamp2 = new Timestamp(EndDate.getYear(),
            EndDate.getMonth(), EndDate.getDay(),
            EndTime.getHours(), EndTime.getMinutes(), 00, 00);

    long milliseconds = timestamp2.getTime() - timestamp1.getTime();
    int seconds = (int) milliseconds / 1000;

    // calculate hours minutes and seconds
    int hours = seconds / 3600;
    int minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60;
    seconds = (seconds % 3600) % 60;
    System.out.println(hours+"h:"+minutes+"m:"+"00s");
```

> Test case

when I give date as 2010-01-05 and date2 as 2010-01-06 I am getting output as below

```
Date 2010-01-05
Date 2010-01-06
TIMEEEEEEEEEE====01:00:00
TIMEEEEEEEEEE====02:00:00
25h:0m:00s
```

when I give date as 2010-01-05 and date2 as 2010-01-11 I am getting output in negative value as below

```
Date 2010-01-05
Date 2010-01-11
TIMEEEEEEEEEE====01:00:00
TIMEEEEEEEEEE====02:00:00
-23h:0m:00s
```

Help me to correct if I am doing something wrong. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you debug your code? Are the dates/timestamps correct or already corrupted? Btw, you should use `Calendar` to build dates instead of the deprecated constructors. Also note that timezones and daylight saving time as well as other influences (leap seconds for example) can influence your manual calculations, i.e. the number of seconds between two dates might not be what you'd expect. Thus I'd suggest using one of the available libraries (e.g. Joda Time or if you're using Java 8 the new built-in date library).

Comment: For reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: You are converting your date in time format so that you are getting like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Manual time calculation:-**

Converts Date in milliseconds (ms) and calculate the differences between two dates, with following rules :

- 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
- 60 seconds = 1 minute
- 60 minutes = 1 hour
- 24 hours = 1 day

**Sample Example:-**

```
package com.dps2.practice.dyuti;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateDifferentExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateStart = "08/11/2016 09:29:58";
        String dateStop = "08/12/2016 10:31:48";

        //HH converts hour in 24 hours format (0-23), day calculation
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date d1 = null;
        Date d2 = null;

        try {
            d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
            d2 = format.parse(dateStop);

            //in milliseconds
            long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

            long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
            long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

            System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
            System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
            System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
            System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Doing this math yourself is silly given that we have the java.time classes at our disposal.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your calculation is this: `StartDate.getDay()` etc.

`getDay()` will return the number of day of the week (read the JavaDoc) and *not* the day of the month. You'll need to use `getDate()` instead.

To illustrate the problem using your values: 2010-01-05 will return 2 for `getDay()` and thus you are getting 2010-01-02 as your timestamp. 2010-01-11 will return 1 for `getDay()` (it's 6 days later, i.e. (2 + 6) % 7 = 1) and hence your second timestamp becomes 2010-01-01. Now the second timestamp is before the first and hence you get a negative value.

However, as I already stated in my comments you should try and use some library or at least the non-deprecated built-in functionality for those calculations to save you a lot of headaches (I suggest you watch this video to get an idea of the challenges: https://youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY ).

Answer (score 3):

The `java.sql` date-time classes are meant only for exchanging data with databases. Do not use them for business logic. Also, they are part of the troublesome, poorly designed, and confusing old legacy date-time classes. Avoid them all.

## java.time

The java.time classes built into Java 8 and later supplant the old classes you are using. Much simpler now.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( "2010-01-06" );
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse ( "01:00" );
LocalDateTime earlier = LocalDateTime.of ( ld , lt );

LocalDateTime later = earlier.plusHours ( 7 );
```

The `Duration` class represents a span of time as a total number of seconds and nanoseconds. Its `toString` method generates a String in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS`. This format uses `P` to mark the beginning, and the `T` to separate year-months-days from hours-minutes-seconds portion. The `Duration` and `Period` classes can both parse and generate such Strings.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( earlier , later );
```

In Java 8, `Duration` class inexplicably lacks getter methods for each part: days, hours, minutes, seconds, fraction-of-second. Java 9 rectifies this omission with new `getPart` methods.

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "earlier: " + earlier + " | later: " + later + " | duration: " + duration );
```

> earlier: 2010-01-06T01:00 | later: 2010-01-06T08:00 | duration: PT7H

## Time zone

Be aware that your inputs lacked any information about offset-from-UTC or time zone. So the math seen above is performed assuming generic 24-hour days. Real-world anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) are ignored.

If you did indeed intend time zones, assign them via the `atZone` method to instantiate `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's a complicated code you have in your question there. You can make it quite easy by using `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` class.

**Output**

```
Date Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 UTC 2010                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Date Wed Jan 06 00:00:00 UTC 2010

difference is:                                                                                                                                                                                                                
24 hours : 1440 minutes : 86400 seconds
```

**Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date = "2010-01-05";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date date3 = null;
        try {
            date3 = sdf1.parse(date);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date StartDate = new Date(date3.getTime());
        System.out.println("Date " + StartDate);

        String date2 = "2010-01-06";
        java.util.Date date4 = null;
        try {
            date4 = sdf1.parse(date2);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        Date EndDate = new Date(date4.getTime());
        System.out.println("Date " + EndDate);



        long dateStart = StartDate.getTime(), dateStop = EndDate.getTime();
        long diff = dateStop - dateStart;

        long diffInSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
        long diffInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);

        System.out.println("\n\ndifference is:\n");
        System.out.println(diffInHours + " hours : " + diffInMinutes + " minutes : " + diffInSeconds + " seconds");
    }
}
```